# Am trying to find which rows are missing a particular worker_role based on existence of another worker_role value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select category_name, event_name 
from security_events_view 
where category_name not in ('ABA Data Collection', 'ABA Session', 'MST Events') 
  and worker_role in ('Program_admin', 'Program_Leader')
having max(case when worker_role = 'Program_admin' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
order by category_name, event_name
```

But I am get an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Column 'security_events_view.category_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The data would look like this:

Input

```
category_name    event_name        Worker_role
----------------------------------------------------
Home             Hair_Brushing     Program_leader
Home             Hair_Brushing     Program_admin
Home             Teeth_Brushing    Program_leader
```

With this input, we want to see

```
Home     Teeth_Brushing
```

as the result set. Since there is no row for `worker_role = Program _admin`

Comment: `having` is used to filter rows after rows are grouped and aggregated. Your query does not include a `group by`, have you tried adding `group by worker_role`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select category_name, event_name 
from security_events_view 
where category_name not in('ABA Data Collection', 'ABA Session', 'MST Events') 
    and worker_role in ('Program_admin', 'Program_Leader')
having max(case when worker_role = 'Program_admin' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
group by category_name, event_name
order by category_name, event_name
```

Comment: HI thanks Shravya- the only issue is on the last row on group- Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.